# what's the difference between javascript class methods w/o and w function keyword?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance

I'm currently learning Javascript class. and I've got a question about class method override.

subclass method without using `function` keyword

```
class Class {
    
    m = function() {
        console.log('super')
    }
}

class Subclass extends Class{
  
    m() {
        console.log('sub')
    }
}

const si = new Subclass()

si.m() // super
```

I think it should print out 'sub' because `Subclass` has method `m`, which I think would override method `m` in its super class `Class`.

If I change subclass method using `function` keyword, then I get what I expected.

```
...

class Subclass extends Class{
    m = function() {
        console.log('sub')
    }
}

...

si.m() // sub
```

Why it is working like these?
What's the difference between methods w and w/o `function` keyword?

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+class+method+vs+class+field+function) of [What is the difference between class method vs property function vs property arrow function in typescript?](/q/56055658/4642212).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `=` uses class field syntax, which is syntax sugar for assigning the property to the instance in the constructor, right after any `super` calls. This

```
class Class {
    
    m = function() {
        console.log('super')
    }
}
```

is the same as

```
class Class {
    constructor() { 
        this.m = function() {
            console.log('super')
        }
    }
}
```

Using `m()` syntax puts the function not on the instance, but on the *prototype*. That is

```
si.hasOwnProperty('m')
```

would return `true` when using class fields, and `false` when using `m()` (method syntax). And

```
si.prototype.hasOwnProperty('m')
```

would return `false` when using class fields, and `true` when using method syntax.

Another small difference is that when using method syntax, the function can't be used as a constructor with `new`.

With your code, the superclass puts `m` directly on the instance. When using method syntax in the subclass, the subclass's `m` is not seen when referencing the instance because the `m` property exists earlier in the prototype chain - on the instance, not on the subclass prototype. When you change the subclass to declare `m` as a class field, you're putting it directly on the instance, overwriting the superclass's assignment to the instance.

I'd usually recommend putting functions as methods (eg `m()`) rather than using class fields when subclassing - it makes inheritance easier. Eg, if you used

```
class Class {
    m() {
        console.log('super')
    }
}
```

`m` would be on the super prototype, so the child class would be able to put `m` either on the child prototype or on the instance (with a class field) and it would overwrite the super's `m` either way.